# What are the benefits to underwriters in a secondary offering?

Tags: stocks

Company A's shares went up *today* due to some great news. Company A stock closes at $10. In the after hours, it releases a PR stating it will do a secondary offering to raise $100M at $8 per share which is about 12.5M shares that will be diluted. In addition, the this news was seen as unfavorable and Company A's stock drops to $8 in the after hours.

The underwriters are receiving a *discount* at $8 per share relative to the share price prior to the secondary. It so happens the market currently values Company A at $8 per share as well. My question is how would the underwriters profit in this scenario?

Of course, the underwriters can *try* and sell their 12.5M shares at a higher price but what if that does not happen?

What are other ways the underwriters profit? I guess my thought process on this is that Wall Street **banksters** never lose.

Comment: Banksters?  Do you really think they never lose?  Have you missed the snapchat IPO?  The blueapron IPO?  Do you have a real life example of a publicly traded company issuing new shares at a 20% discount to market?  Do you know what role an underwriter plays in the process?

Comment: "Underwriters make their income from the price difference (the "underwriting spread") between the price they pay the issuer and what they collect from investors or from broker-dealers who buy portions of the offering." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underwriting#Securities_underwriting

Comment: @quid i saw both IPOs. I believe for SNAP, they were able to dump it all on retail. APRN, not so much?

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD thank you, I was looking for something along these lines.

Comment: @quid I do believe banksters do not lose, they will recover their "losses" through other avenues, ie: upgrades, downgrades, manipulation?, etc. But for sake of this question, I'm more interested in something like the underwriting spread.

Comment: @user7386539, you believe, based on what? Your through understanding of the process...

Comment: @quid please enlighten me on the role of an underwriter.

Answer (score 2):

Your impression about banks and bankers is very wrong.  Wall street banks can and often do lose in transactions.  In fact, banks go bankrupt and/or require massive bailouts to survive because they sometimes lose a ton of money.  The business of investment banking often involves bearing risk for customers, which, by definition, means they lose some of the time.  Generally the risks they take on individual transactions are not large enough to bring the whole bank down, but sometimes they are.  Banking is a job like any other, except that it has more risk than most.

Anyway, to your point, how do underwriters make money on shares that fall in value before the sale?  **On the commission**.  The issuing company will normally pay the investment bank a percentage of the funds raised in the offering, regardless of the price.  Of course, it's possible for the bank to still lose money if their contract stipulates a minimum price and they are not able to meet it.  In that case, the bank may lose on that offering, contradicting your preconceived notion.

By the way, one other question implicit in your post: Why was the secondary offering considered bad news?  If the CEO and other insiders have private information that indicates that the stock is overvalued, then doing a secondary offering at the inflated price will greatly enrich them.  Because this happens some times, investors are wary about secondary offerings.  This makes companies that would otherwise do a secondary offering shy away from it, even if shares are not overpriced.  Therefore if a company is doing a secondary offering, the market is likely to worry that the stock is overvalued even at a reduced price.